# HTML Newsarticles using HTML forms, php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

As the webmaster from the local tabletennisclub, I want to delegate the possibility in adding newsarticles.
(This article will be included in the website) [Home page](http://www.mttv72.nl)

Only the newsarticle content is saved in a specific MySQL table.

I've created a HTML form with a textarea field for this.[HTML Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lycLZ.png)

This field has to include HTML codes. such as `<p></p>`, `</br>`, `<strong></strong>`, `<table></table>`, ....

In php I use

```
function SchrijfNwsGegWeg( $actie, $U ) {
    $query  = "INSERT INTO `Tbl_Nieuws` (";
    $query .= "`Editor`, ";
    $query .= "`Auteur`, ";
    $query .= "`Titel`, ";
    $query .= "`IntroTekst`, ";
    $query .= "`Verhaal`, ";
    $query .= "`Categorie` ) VALUES (";

    $query .= MaakValue($_SESSION['Gebruikersnaam']).", ";  // Editor
    $query .= MaakValue($U['Auteur']).", ";
    $query .= MaakValue($U['Titel']).", ";
    $query .= MaakValue($U['IntroTekst']).", ";
    $query .= $U['Verhaal'].", ";
    $query .= MaakValue($U['Categorie'])." )";

    $result=mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: '.mysql_error());
    // echo '<p>'.$query.'</p>';

    if ($result) echo 'Artikel '.$U['IntroTekst'].' is toegevoegd.';
    else echo 'er is een fout opgetreden, graag artikel opnieuw toevoegen.';

    header ('Location: http://www.mttv72.nl/index.php?pid=Beheer/B_Menu');
}   // function SchrijfGegWeg
```

When these entries are submitted, I get an SQL error message that the syntax is not correct.

When I use the same syntax directly in the MySQL database no error occurs.

Comment: What's a MaakValue

Comment: What's the actual query that's being passed to mysql_query()? As you're using a function (MaakValue) to create bits of the query, it's impossible to debug without knowing what that function is returning. Also, especially if $U is coming from user input, your code is at risk of SQL injection. You should read up on PDO and avoid using the deprecated `mysql_` functions at all times. "PHP: The Right Way" is a great resource for PHP best practices: http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases

Comment: I think better to make query in one line variable.